# Adding Device UDID to XCode

Tags: iphone, xcode

I am familiar with adding the device UDID to the developer portal…I don't want to add ids overthere .Instead of that I would like to add device ID through Xcode…..Is it possible to add devices through Xcode…..

Answer (score 0):

As far as my knowledge it is not possible.

Answer (score 0):

no you cant ..but you can buy a developer license for 1 device it cost 15$ (google for it) .. guys often used it to install crack applications without jelly break his device.

Answer (score 0):

In XCode 4.2, if you open up the 'Organizer' and click your device in the left menu, there is a button in the bottom of the view, saying 'Add to Portal'. I think that does what you want.